# Restrict viewable content to user that created it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Thank you for taking the time. I'm looking to make a web app that displays posts only to the user that created that post. I'm using Rails 4 and the Devise Gem for authentication. I'm thinking there might be a way using scope, but have hit a wall.

Here is a link to my project on github:

https://github.com/sunkencity999/scratchitoff

Answer (score 1):

In your controller (let's assume its PostController) you can write something like this:

```
class PostsController << ApplicationController
    before_filter :restrict_user, :only => [:show, :view, :edit, :delete, :update]

    def show

    end

   def view
   end

   def edit
   end

   def delete
   end

   def update
   end

   private
   def restrict_user
       begin
           @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id].to_i)
       rescue
           redirect_to "/", :error => "You don't have access to that post"
       end
   end
end
```

You can access the post in your view using @post

The before_filter action gets executed right before the controller action. 
The restrict_user action checks if a POST with the given ID exists in the current_user scope.
If so, it assigns that post to the @post instance variable and if not it redirects to the root-route (/) with an error message.

You can use different approaches for this, another solution might be:

```
def restrict_user
    @post = current_user.posts.where(:id => params[:id].to_i)
    if @post.nil?
        # no access. your code logic here.
    else
        # user has access to that post do further code logic here.
    end
end
```

You can also use gems like Pundit to use authorization.

EDIT: Just checked your github repo, looks like you're using Pundit already.
Then you should edit the `PostPolicy` in /app/policies/post_policy.rb to something like this:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def index?
    user.present? and post.user_id == current_user.id
  end
end
```

Haven't had the time to test this. If you're having trouble I can test it on my machine.
Also note that this change doesn't affect other methods (like view, edit, delete, update). So you should adapt the changes I made to the index? action to these methods as well.

Comment: If I could ask for one more bit of help? Using your method I get this error:
undefined local variable or method `post'

Comment: Where do you get this error? In your views or in the controller? Could you commit your changes?